# generating csrf token in facebook account kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Facebook account kit for web Javascript. However, I see that it involves csrf token. Where should the csrf token be generated? It's a react web app so I am puzzled about this. As per the docs of Facebook,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/webjs/

I see that as per the docs, they are generating csrf on server side using php or nodejs. Can we generate csrf token on client side?

I want to use this [react-facebook-kit](https://github.com/zsajjad/react-facebook-account-kit)

My concern is that it just receives a csrf token as a prop.

Comment: You should generate csrf token in backend, send it to client and client sends it back to backend where you can verify it. If you generate it in client it kinda loses its purpose.

Comment: @Cray Can we do facebook account kit otp  without csrf ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with it, but probably, which does not mean you should if it's a security threat.